# DigiCert says "Your server is not sending the right intermediate certificates" for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, ssl

We have tight security setting our our network, that seem to be preventing Stack Overflow from loading. I did some digging and found that the static page that supplies the CSS and other static content to Stack Overflow is a HTTPS address. So my first step was to change this to a HTTP address and WAM! the site loads.

So I went to DigiCert's [SSL Installation Diagnostics Tool](http://www.digicert.com/help/?host=www.stackoverflow.com) to check the SSL certificate (of www.stackoverflow.com), and it returns the following error:

> Your server is not sending the right intermediate certificates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you checking www.stackoverflow.com? That's not where the CSS is loaded from. Also, note the message "Certificate does not match name www.stackoverflow.com". The [validation is fine for cdn.sstatic.net](http://www.digicert.com/help/?host=cdn.sstatic.net).

Comment: The SSL cert is for *.stackexchange.com, which obviously doesn't cover stackoverflow.com.  Been this way forever.  Not sure if they will ever do anything about it.  Looking for a dupe.

Comment: Odd that digicert couldn't figure out such a simple issue and tell you in a clear manner what was going on.  Doesn't bode well for them, imho.

Comment: I checked the same in SSL Checker tool but its not like that you said, It gives all the details about the installed SSL in Stackoverflow. So its not the problem by digicert or stackoverflow.